# "И днем(,) и ночью кот ученый..."

Tags: пунктуация

Попался в интернете тест: "нужна ли запятая в строчке из стихотворения, приведенного в заголовке вопроса". Я написал, что нет, не нужна. Честно говоря, ответил интуитивно. Прав ли я, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть правило о том, что однородные члены, соединенные повторяющимся союзом, не отделяются запятой, если образуют цельное выражение: и тот и другой, и днем и ночью, и летом и зимой, и стар и млад...